# Batch Emails with wp_mail()

Tags: email, mailing-list

I've searched all over Google with no luck. Can someone point me in the right direction for learning how to send out batch emails with the `wp_mail()` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While according to [`wp_mail()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail) docs you can pass array of emails addressees it would be bad email tone since it will expose addresses between them.

There is no explicit bcc (blind copy) argument from [quick look at source it does seems to be processed if passed in headers](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.0.4/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L351).

Note that many hosting providers are very nervous about mass outgoing emails and can react... poorly. :) It's better to check in advance how many and how often emails you are allowed to send.

Comment: I've already managed to send out the emails with BCC, and I'm well aware of the number of emails I'm allowed to send. I have a newsletter plugin that I need to work with more than, say, 50 subscribers, which is about the limit I can send out with a single email.

Comment: @Pippin if you have email send worked out for 50/email, why not just split complete list in such chunks and send out sequentially?

Comment: Thought about that, just haven't come up with the best way to do it, while working with the constraints of other features of the plugin.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm managing my own server using sendmail and I'm wondering if BCC is the way to go or if I should use something like SwiftMailer.